# How to mount a FileVault2 encrypted removable media in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, macos-sierra, filevault

I have a removable media that encrypted with FileVault2 in macOS Sierra.
I want to mount the media with Ubuntu.
I tried to use libFVDE and fvdemount, but I think they don't support/work with removable media.